# Bokeh plot filled semicircle

Tags: plot, bokeh, glyph

I would like to plot a filled semicircle in bokeh to show a model of filling a pipe (https://www.engineersedge.com/fluid_flow/partially_full_pipe_flow_calculation/image003.png) where, based on user input, the water level changes. I looked at the available glyphs (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs.html) but wasn't able to find one that would work. I was hoping I could fill the arc glyph but it doesn't seem like that is possible.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to do just that. Looking at the diagram you linked, you could combine a `wedge` glyph (for the "pacman" part) and a patch to fill in the rest.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from math import pi, sin, cos

p = figure(match_aspect=True)
p.wedge(x=0, y=0, radius=1, start_angle=-5*pi/4, end_angle=pi/4)
p.patch(x=[0, -cos(pi/4), cos(pi/4)], y=[0, sin(pi/4), sin(pi/4)])

p.circle(0, 0, radius=1, fill_color=None, line_color="black", line_width=3)

# hack: Bokeh does not yet auto-range this odd combination well
p.rect(0, 0, 2, 2, color=None)

show(p)
```

[image]

If these need to be updated somehow, you'd probably want to wrap this up in some helper function to generate the right data values and [update ColumnDataSources for the existing glyphs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#columndatasource). Best practice is to draw glyphs once up front when possible then later update only their data sources if they need to change.

A couple of final notes:

- you need `match_aspect=True` to ensure aspect ratios in "pixel space" and "data space" are the same, which is necessary to make sure the circle is actually a circle in "data space"
- `match_aspect` requires you use the default auto-ranges. If you set explicit range values, Bokeh trusts you know what you want, even if this messes up the aspect.
- This is an odd combination of single glyphs... the auto-ranges do not do great on them by themselves. I added an invisible rect around the circle to help it out.